# XCode 5 -- Jump To Previous Cursor Location

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode5, hotkeys

I would like to jump to the previous cursor position *within a file* in XCode 5 (with either a keyboard hotkey or a drop-down menu path).

This SO post worked for XCode 3: [Does XCode have a cursor navigation stack like Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178892/does-xcode-have-a-cursor-navigation-stack-like-visual-studio)

But for XCode 5, I could not find this functionality here: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Machx/Xcode-Keyboard-Shortcuts/Xcode_Shortcuts.pdf, nor in the Apple Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010560-CH1-SW1

**EDIT**

Sorry I wasn't clear earlier. I do not want to switch *between* files. As the answers below state, that is what ctrl+cmd+left/right does. I want to switch between cursor positions *within* a file. For example:

I am working in MyViewController.m.

I write a function -(void)doStuff at line 178.

In -(void)doStuff, I realize that I need to update an @property to be readwrite.

I go to the top of MyViewController.m to line 10. I add the line @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray *myArray;

Now I want to return to finish writing my -(void)doStuff method. **What is the best way to get there?** This is when I'd like to say "Go to the last text cursor position."

Comment: doesn't the left arrow above the file editor do just that?

Comment: Could you tell me what works for you. XCode is driving me nuts.

Comment: I use @LucasTimza 's accepted answer.

Comment: In XCode 8.
cmd+ctrl + -> works just great.

It moves you to previous cursor position, not to the previous visited file.

Comment: Amazing plugin for navigation, but it can't be installed with modern Xcode(( https://github.com/merrickp/JumpMarks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A useful trick I found is to bind opening the Document Items menu (by default `Ctrl + 6`) to something easier to type for me. Then when I'm about to, say, jump to some method definition (that may or may not be in the same file I'm already in), I first open the Document Items menu then just hit `Enter`. That marks my current location in the navigation stack. It also marks the line the cursor is at in the current method, too.

[image]

It takes a little training to remember to mark your place, but being able to open that menu and hit `Enter` quickly from the keyboard makes it less painful to force Xcode to mark your navigation within a single file.

Comment: Very cool solution. How do you bind opening the Documents Items menu to something other than `ctrl + 6`? I think that'd be a helpful addition to this answer.

Comment: You can change it in Xcode's Key Bindings preferences, just like any of the other commands.

Comment: Yeah, dumb question, sorry. I just changed mine to cmd+enter and it works great!

Comment: this is really bad, having to go through this pain just to mark your current position which be a feature in an IDE the scale of xcode

Answer (score 14):

As Owen commented on your post, I believe the behaviour you want is to `Go Forward/Backward`, which is a behaviour represented by those two arrows at the top left of the text entry field:

[image: Location of Go Forward/Backward buttons]

In the pdf you linked these actions actually have shortcuts to the keys `cmd+control+arrow`, where the arrow key you press represents forward/backward motion through your XCode behaviour (left being back, right being forward).

Comment: cant even tell you how USEFUL this answer was

Comment: Though helpful, this isn't my intended use case. See edit for clarification.

Comment: Technically in that use case this would still work, as long as you didn't visit some other file in between the two actions.

Comment: `Cmd+control+arrow` does not work in this use case. `cmd+control+arrow` only works to switch _between_ files, not within a _single_ file. `cmd+control+arrow` does not move my cursor from line 10 to line 187 within a _single_ file.

Answer (score 8):

`cmd+ctrl+arrow` can work in this situation. But, it depends on *how* you change cursor locations.

If you use a file navigation control to change cursor location, `cmd+ctrl+arrow` will work. `ctrl+6` switches to a method within a given file. If you start on line 178 then `ctrl+6` to switch to another method on line 10, `cmd+ctrl+arrow` will return your cursor to line 178.

If you manually change cursor location, `cmd+ctrl+arrow` will **not** work. If you start on line 178 then scroll to line 10, `cmd+ctrl+arrow` will **not** return your cursor to line 178.

Answer (score 6):

I was searching for this for so long time and what works for me is:

⌃ + 2 (Ctrl + 2 - Shows previous history) then click ↓ - this will jump back to previous definition

⌃ + 3 (Ctrl + 3 - Shows next history) then click ↓ - this will jump to next definition

This will only work if you navigate through your class using ⌃ + 6 to jump between definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Xcode does not comes up with this feature . but If you are going to different line for copy content to paste to previous location then  tricky using (Undo and Redo) **Command + Z** and then **Shift +command +Z** shortcut key one short simulate same effect.

Answer (score -1):

`Ctrl-command-leftKey` does exactly that. (It's called "Go Back" in the documentation).

Comment: its not taking the cursor last location. On the contrary its taking to last file file opened.